# How to add precompiled headers in CMake for visual studio generator

Tags: c++, cmake

CMake 3.18; VS 2019;

I'm learning CMake and to check my results I'm trying to generate visual studio project.
My current problem is precompiled header option.
What I want to achieve is that VS project will have "/use" or "/create" precompiled headers option with correct file name.

In my project folder I already have ugpch.h & ugpch.cpp files, which stands for precompiled headers.
I've tryied to use `target_precompile_headers(UGame PRIVATE Source/ugpch.h)` instruction in my cmakelists, but that has no effect on my visual studio precompiled header option.
What is the correct way to do this?

**Edit**: I've updated my cmake to 3.18 version, but still no effect that I expected in my generated visual studio project.
Instead I found new folder "Precompile header files" with cmake_pch.cxx file.. It looks like `target_precompile_headers` did something totally different from what I expected

Comment: Can you show the rest of your CMake file? Also, is the file path and file name correct? You mention you created `pch.h` but your CMake command specifies the file as `Source/ugpch.h`...

Comment: Here is the documentation for [`target_precompile_headers`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.17/command/target_precompile_headers.html). See that CMake generates the PCH files *for you*.

Comment: @squareskittles thanks for pointing out, I've corrected my spelling issue, but still no effect

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The command `target_precompile_headers` has been added in CMake 3.16.

You'll either have to upgrade your CMake distribution (The one shipped inside VS2019 is quite up to date) or install the latest from the installer.

Otherwise, you'll have to use cotire for precompiled header, but my recommendation would be to upgrade since it's usually quite easy to do, and you probably already have an up to date version on your computer shipped with visual studio.

---

Since you updated your question.

The command `target_precompile_headers` is not doing what you think. You don't provide your PCH there, you provide what header should be part of the generated PCH. If the file `ugpch.h` contains includes for `headera.h`, `headerb.h` and `headerc.h`, then your precompiled header command should look like this:

```
target_precompile_headers(UGame PRIVATE headera.h headerb.h headerc.h)
```

The actual precompiled header will be generated by CMake.

Of course, you can still use `ugpch.h` as your precompiled header. CMake will simply use it to generate its own. As you observed.

After that, remove manual inclusion of the header. It will be included automatically.

From the CMake documentation:

> The list of header files is used to generate a header file named cmake_pch.h|xx which is used to generate the precompiled header file (.pch, .gch, .pchi) artifact. The cmake_pch.h|xx header file will be force included (-include for GCC, /FI for MSVC) to all source files, so sources do not need to have #include "pch.h".

Why does it work like that you ask? CMake support `PUBLIC` precompiled header. If you link to multiple target that each have public precompiled headers, then your target inherit all of them. Since compilers usually accept one precompiled header, CMake has to generate agglomerated headers for that to work.

Answer (score 1):

Using an older version of cmake...
i've used the /Yc and [/Yu](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/yu-use-precompiled-header-file?view=vs-2019) compiler flag with visual studio.
It is not as universal as target_precompile_headers(UGame PRIVATE Source/ugpch.h) but should do the trick :)