# How to generate precompiled headers for MSVC using Cmake

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake

I'm trying to generate precompiled headers to my project using `target_precompiled_headers()`. I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62541168/how-to-add-precompiled-headers-in-cmake-for-visual-studio-generator) answer explaining the function, but I fail to make it work. The header isn't added to `.cpp` files and it generates four `.hxx` files.

My code:

- #CMakeLists.txt

```
# Collect files
set(ENGINE_WINDOW
    # window
    "src/window/window.h"
    "src/window/window.cpp"
)

# Set filters
source_group("window"   FILES ${ENGINE_WINDOW})

# Build static library
add_library(engine STATIC
    ${ENGINE_WINDOW}
)

# Precompile headers
target_precompile_headers(engine PRIVATE 
    <iostream>
)

# Specify include directories
target_include_directories(engine
    PUBLIC ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/vendor/glad/include
)

# Find OpenGL
find_package(OpenGL)

# Link libraries to engine
target_link_libraries(engine
    ${OPENGL_gl_LIBRARY}
    glad
    glfw
)
```

- Generated cmake_pch.hxx (x4)

```
/* generated by CMake */

#pragma system_header
#ifdef __cplusplus
#include <iostream>
#endif // __cplusplus
```

- Generate cmake_pch.cpp (which is empty)

```
/* generated by CMake */
```

[Output of CMake generated precompiled headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rLgNn.png)

Comment: Can you show some console output that demonstrates the problem, or can you reduce the problem here to a minimal, reproducible case? From what you've shown here, it appears CMake is operating correctly.

Comment: I added a zip with the problem reduced to a minimum.

Comment: As said in cmake-document ---- The cmake_pch.h|xx header file will be force included (-include for GCC, /FI for MSVC) to all source files. ---- You'd better check your actual "CL.EXE" command, there should be some "/FI cmake_pch.hxx"

Comment: I understand now. @caoanan If you make it an answer I can accept it.